# How to have a file with a normal name using storage in laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

I have this code:

```
public function storeProject(Request $request)
    {
        $project = new Project();
        if ($request->has('slug') || $request->has('position') || $request->has('public')
        || $request->has('pathheader') || $request->has('pathhome'))
        {
            $project->slug = $request->input('slug');
            $namefolder = $project->slug;
            $project->position = $request->input('position');
            $project->public = $request->input('public');
            $file = $request->file('pathheader');
            $file2 = $request->file('pathhome');
            Storage::put('projects/'.$namefolder, $file);
            //\Storage::disk('projects')->put($namefolder, \File::get($file2));
            //File::makeDirectory('/assets/img/projects/hola', 0775, true);
            $project->save();
            return $project;
            return $file;
        }
    }
```

And when this function is used /projects/.$namefolder is created correctly, but the file name is something like this: p5ds31F6iJoZxXypSMlp3z1baKXs5tPAVOaKMGav.png

How to have for example: 'header.png'?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`storeAs()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files) method:

```
$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg');
```

> If you do not want a file name to be automatically generated, you may use the `storeAs` method, which accepts the path, file name, and disk name as its arguments.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: The problem is i need to create the directory if not exists.. so when i do the "storage" like you say, i think i need have the directory created..